# Hide newly created page from top navigation menu

Tags: sharepoint

I need to that after page creation newly created page won't appear in top navigation. Can someone suggest me any ways how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

UPD: I need whatever created page won't appear in top navigation by default, because my users don't have access to settings.

Answer (score 2):

Go to site settings/modify navigation and uncheck show pages.

Comment: I probably do not precisely described my problem. I need whatever created page won't appear in top navigation by default, because my users don't have access to settings.